# Textfield does not change text

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I created a class test with many data members of which one is a JTextField called myField. During the construction, I create a blank text field.

My problem is that, the contents of the text field never changes after construction if I use setText method.

```
class test extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField myField;
    public test()
    {
        //constructer
    }
    private void setTheLayout()
    {
        // did layout positioning for myField
        add(myField);
    }
    private void setAValue() //called on a button click
    {
        myField.setText("Hello world");
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you debug this and are you sure the method is invoked? Please, discard the possibility of the button being the one in trouble.

Comment: you have not initialized  `myField`

Comment: Did you implement an ActionListener on the button?

Comment: yes. I rechecked. The method is being called but the text is never updated.
A System.out.println inside the method prints it. Only the setText() never works

Comment: yes.I used action listener
edit.addActionListener
        (
            new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    setAValue();
                }
            }
        );

Comment: For better help post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) probably doing this you'll get the solution by yourself

Comment: `It is done automatically.` - Swing components do not get created automatically. If you think the IDE is creating the text field for you then this would mean you have created two text fields. One that is displayed in the frame and one that is declared (but not defined in your class). The text field in your `test` class is NOT the same text field that is displayed in the frame.

Comment: Agree the advice of @camickr and nachokk. Mainly the error in your program is in code not shown, and you need to do some serious debugging. Create your [sscce](http://sscce.org) and post it here if you want us to have a prayer of being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change:      `private JTextField myField;` To: `private JTextField
   myField = new JTextField("");`

I think this is what you need.